# hhline - one "missing" line

Tags: tables

I want to create a graphic with a tabular environment, but I can't figure out how I get a line under the "03" field.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,parskip=half,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|ccccc}
\hhline{---}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{05} & &\\\hhline{===-}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{01} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{04}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{09} & \\\hhline{====-}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{06} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{08} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{03}\\\hhline{====}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{06} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{02} & \\\hhline{----}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\cline{5-5}\hhline{====}` to the end of row 3

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,parskip=half,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|ccccc}
\hhline{---}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{05} & &\\\hhline{===-}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{01} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{04}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{18} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{09} & \\\hhline{====-}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{06} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{08} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{03}\\\cline{5-5}\hhline{====}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{06} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{07} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{02} & \\\hhline{----}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same, except I simplify the code:with `hhline`, you don't need all those \multicolumns, and I prefer to put the vertical lines in the preamble of the table: it suffices to define an `\emptycells` command that suppresses the vertical lines when required.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,ngerman,parskip=half,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{array}


\newcommand*\emptycell{\emptycells{1}}
\newcommand*\emptycells[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hhline{---}
10 & 07 & 05 & \emptycells{2} \\
\hhline{===-}
01 & 04 & 18 & 09 & \emptycell \\
\hhline{====-}
06 & 08 & 11 & 07 & 03 \\
\cline{5-5}\hhline{====}
06 & 11 & 07 & 02 & \emptycell \\
\hhline{----}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]